# How to skip properties in destination source in modelmapper?

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I have two classes. RequestDTO and Entity. I want to map RequestDTO to the Entity. In that case, I want to insert one of the Entity property manually which means that property is not in the Request DTO. How to achieve this using modelmapper.

```
public class RequestDTO {

    private String priceType;

    private String batchType;
}

public class Entity {


    private long id;

    private String priceType;

    private String batchType;
}

Entity newEntity = modelMapper.map(requestDto, Entity.class);
```

But this does not work, it says it can't convert string to long. I request a solution to this or a better approach to this.

Comment: From what I've understood from your question, your RequestDTO has no id. Am I right?

Comment: yes@MatheusCirillo

Comment: Please, can you show us the request you`re sending?

Comment: Above I mentioned the requestdto class. I just edited it now earlier it wasnot their by my mistake. I just sent a request body. with the priceType and  batchType. and want to add id manually. to the Entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to perform the mapping manually (ideally for dissimilar objects)**

You can check the documentation for dissimilar object mapping [Property Mapping](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/),

> You can define a property mapping by using method references to match
>   a source getter and destination setter.

```
typeMap.addMapping(Source::getFirstName, Destination::setName);
```

> The source and destination types do not need to match.

```
 typeMap.addMapping(Source::getAge, Destination::setAgeString);
```

**If you don't want to do the mapping field by field to avoid boilerplate code**

you can configure a skip mapper, to avoid mapping certain fields to your destination model:

```
modelMapper.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.skip(Entity::setId));
```

---

I've created a test for your case and the mapping works for both side ***without configuring anything*** :

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertNotNull;

public class ModelMapperTest {

    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        this.modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    }

    @Test
    public void fromSourceToDestination() {
        Source source = new Source(1L, "Hello");
        Destination destination = modelMapper.map(source, Destination.class);
        assertNotNull(destination);
        assertEquals("Hello", destination.getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void fromDestinationToSource() {
        Destination destination = new Destination("olleH");
        Source source = modelMapper.map(destination, Source.class);
        assertNotNull(source);
        assertEquals("olleH", destination.getName());
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Source {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Destination {
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here should I need to map all others or the required property is enough. Since they use typemap except modelmap.

Comment: Are you configuring the ModelMapper ? because I've just done a test both ways ( from RequestDTO --> Entity and from Entity --> RequestDTO. And it works fine

Comment: I actually have the same problem,  if the destination has more fields than source, the conversion fails